# Codeigniter: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm moving my website online, but when i edit my table data i got errors like this,

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/shintiad/public_html/sociotraveler/application/views/template/index.php:20)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 688

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/shintiad/public_html/sociotraveler/application/views/template/index.php:20)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 542
```

my template/index.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <!-- Meta -->
        <?php $this->load->view('template/partial/meta');?>
        <!-- Meta -->
  </head>
  <body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <?php $this->load->view('template/partial/sidebar');?>
        <!-- Header -->

        <!-- Dynamic Content -->
        <div class="content">
        <?php $this->load->view("{$page_info->content}");?>
        </div>
        <!-- Dynamic Content -->

        <!-- Footer -->
        <?php $this->load->view('template/partial/footer');?>
        <!-- Footer -->
   </body>
  </html>
```

when i ran it on my localhost everything was alright..Please help, thank you...
*i've checking white space before

Comment: try check if there is a blank space before the `<?php` tag in any of your controllers or models

Comment: @ViPiN i've checking everything but still got the error

Comment: from my understand this happens when you try to redirect from a page which already gave an output

Comment: @shintia i think you use the closing tag of php in one of your controller

Answer (score 1):

Please Check all PHP files and remove the whitespace before the `<?php` tag. If there is a space or new line, the body of the http request is started, and you can't add new headers to the http request.